A type of prize-collecting problem in bipartite graph
Consider a bipartite graph with two node sets N1 and N2. Denote by N1(n) the nodes in N1 having edges to node n in N2. Node n in N2 is said to be “covered”, if all nodes in N1(n) are “activated”.   The task is to determine which nodes in N1 to activate, to maximize the number of covered nodes in N2 minus the number of activated nodes in N1. (If the former is not greater than the latter, the optimum is to not activate any node in N1, with objective function value zero.) Anyone knows the problem complexity and/or solution algorithm?

What's the context where you encountered this? Can you credit the original source? What concepts have been introduced in this chapter of the textbook or this module of the course, and what are your thoughts about applying them? What's the best algorithm you have found so far? Could you solve the problem if we didn't subtract the number of activated nodes? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-like problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find this page helpful in improving your question.
